# How to log useful error if scala play config files missing?

Tags: scala, playframework

Is it possible to give a better error message if the config filename is mistyped when using scala play.api.Configuration

e.g. if I run my application with `sbt run -J-Dconfig.file=conf/my-config.conf` but the file is actually called `my_config.conf`, there is no error raised about file not found, but instead the first time the error is raised is when `applicationConfig.has(configPath)` is called, at which point it is not clear how to determine programatically the difference between a missing config value in the file or a missing config file.

Comment: Maybe you need to propose that in https://gitter.im/playframework/playframework or raise an issue on Github. See my answer for a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I do:

- Wrap the configuration in a Config-Class.
- Initialize that class on startup.
- Log all property - values.

This will log exceptions on Startup. Here is an example: [AdaptersContext.scala](https://github.com/pme123/scala-adapters/blob/master/server/app/pme123/adapters/server/entity/AdaptersContext.scala)

As a remark:

If you have your config-file in the `conf` directory (on classpath), use:

`config.resource=demo.conf`